# stream operators where lhs is not a std::iostream instance

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, iostream

I have a custom output class that has two `std::ostream` members that serve different purposes.  Either stream is used depending upon how the output class is configured.  In some instances, the two streams are chained together.  A grossly simplified version of the class is below.  I can provide some more details if needed.

```
class c_Output
{
  public:
    c_Output (bool x_useA) : m_useA(x_useA) { /* setup m_stream[AB] here */ };
    ~c_Output ();
    inline std::ostream& stream () { return (m_useA ? m_streamA : m_streamB); };

  private:
    bool m_useA;
    std::ostream m_streamA;
    std::ostream m_streamB;
}
```

I know how to write stream operators for classes that I wish to stream to/from `std::cout`,  `std::cin`, or any other `std::iostream`, but I am struggling to write stream operators where a `c_Output` instance serves as the lhs instead of a `std::ostream` instance.

Right now, I am able to get away with:

```
c_Output l_output;
uint64_t l_value = 0xc001c0de;
l_output.stream() << std::hex << std::setw(16) << std::setfill('0') << l_value;
```

`c_Output::stream()` returns the appropriate `std::ostream&`, so this behaves just as expected.

I would like to rewrite the above as:

```
c_Output l_output;
uint64_t l_value = 0xc001c0de;
l_output << std::hex << std::setw(16) << std::setfill('0') << l_value;
```

I have attempted several different versions of defining `operator<<` based on examples I have seen here on StackOverflow and the greater web to no avail.  The latest version looks like this:

```
// in header
class c_Output
{
    ...
    friend c_Output& operator<< (c_Output& x_output, std::ostream& x_stream);
    ...
}

// in source
c_Output&
operator<< (c_Output& x_output, std::ostream& x_stream)
{
    x_output.stream() << x_stream;
    return x_output;
}
```

The setup of the arguments is intended to mirror the standard stream operator overload.  This setup gives me compile issues such as:

```
error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'l_output << std::hex'
note: candidates are: c_Output& operator<<(c_Output&, std::ostream&)
```

I have stripped away all the file and line information, but it gets the point across.  I am obviously getting the type for the rhs of the operator incorrect.  What is the correct type and/or correct means of implementing the stream operator as desired?

There is also a complementary `c_Input` class that has a similar requirement, but adapting the answer for `c_Output` should be trivial.

Comment: Do you have a problem with using your l_output.stream() approach?  Short of using template programming, I'm not sure if there's a good solution for this, though I'll have to get back to you on that tomorrow when sober.

Comment: I may have had a eureka moment while driving home from the office, so I cannot test out this idea until the morning.

Comment: (did not realize that enter posts the comment; cont of above)
I can simply replace the rhs with a template argument and let the compiler worry about stitching the cascading stream operators together.

I also am thinking about changing the return type to `void` as I do not want to allow subsequent cascading (i.e. `blah << l_output << blah`.

Comment: @leetNightshade nothing wrong with the original approach except I want to make things easier/obvious for my colleagues.

enjoy your night

Answer (score 0):

The type of [std::hex](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/hex/) is `std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&)`. Change your operator signature to:

```
c_Output& operator<< (c_Output& x_output, std::ios_base& (*x_stream)(std::ios_base&));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
operator<< (c_Output& x_output, std::ostream& x_stream)
```

The only real problem is that `std::hex` isn't a `std::ostream`, and with your methods no overloaded `<<` is available for it.

In order to support the usage of the `hex` modifier, you'll need another `friend` overload with parameters `(c_Output&, ios_base& (*)(ios_base&))` (as [`hex` is a pointer to function taking reference to `ios_base` returning reference to `ios_base`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/hex/)).

At the rate you're going, you'll need to also implement [all the other `<<` overloads](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/) as well. This is not a trivial task, but is necessary to masquerade as a `std::ostream`, with or without inheriting from it.